# How do you uninstall applications in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to uninstall software on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/144387/how-to-uninstall-software-on-a-mac)
>   [Uninstall on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/92504/uninstall-on-mac-os-x)
>   [Removing all traces of a program on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/158159/removing-all-traces-of-a-program-on-mac-os-x)

Some applications look like simple image files (total = 1) living in the Applications folder. I suspect these can simply be trashed directly.

Other applications use a more complex installer, setting up folder and files in various places. A good example of this is SpringTools Suite, which puts the main application folder in the user's home directory and a working directory in the user's Documents directory. While some installers come with an "uninstall" option, some - such as STS - do not.

How can you safely and cleanly uninstall an application whose installer doesn't come with the option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to uninstall software on Mac](http://superuser.com/questions/144387/how-to-uninstall-software-on-mac) and [Uninstall on Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/92504/uninstall-on-mac-os-x) and  [Do I need to bother about correctly uninstalling Mac software?](http://superuser.com/questions/34314/do-i-need-to-bother-about-correctly-uninstalling-mac-software) and [Removing all traces of a program on Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/158159/removing-all-traces-of-a-program-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: @Arjan - While the title would imply that this is a dupe, the content is different.

Comment: @Mark, I actually don't see how it's different? (And meanwhile I've also added other duplicates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no obvious way like drag-to-trash or a separate uninstaller, then the answer would be "it depends." It would vary from application to application, since you would most likely have to delete components by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/), it's usually good at finding the /Users/myself/.myapp and such files applications disseminate out of their .app container.

Comment: This is indeed a very handy tool, i use it myself. But it can't handle all applications (STS is a good example). IMHO MarkM gave the best answer, but this tool is worth mentioning!

Answer (score 0):

The .app files are not files but they are "containers" of software, similar to a .deb package in linux.
The main difference within .app and .dmg is that if you delete a .app contained you also remove all the files associated with it.

Comment: .app-"files" are actually directories containing the program itself (or sometimes programs, plural), required resources, libraries, etc. I.e. everything the Application consists of. -- A .dmg-file is a disk image. .apps are usually distributed on .dmg images. Removing the .app OR the .dmg doesn't automagically remove all files associated to it (i.e. preference files etc.). -- A .deb is a package archive contains an application and resources (just like an .app) and information on how to install the application (while an .app can run without installation!)

Answer (score 0):

For standalone applications, use [TrashMe](http://trashme.jibapps.com/).

For apps done with an installer, a good installer will come with an uninstaller.  If not, check the software website for uninstall instructions.